# JS: Timer continue even after page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to edit this so that the timer won't be updated each time the page is refreshed.

I searched and AJAX in my case is not an option because my code pages need to be refreshed while the timer is still the same.

Also, I tried to save it in a session but that didn't work for JS.

JS:

```
  var mins
  var secs;

function cd() {
mins = 1 * m("5"); // change minutes here
secs = 0 + s(":01"); 
redo();
}

function m(obj) {
for(var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    if(obj.substring(i, i + 1) == ":")
    break;
}
return(obj.substring(0, i));
 }

  function s(obj) {
for(var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    if(obj.substring(i, i + 1) == ":")
    break;
}
return(obj.substring(i + 1, obj.length));
}

function dis(mins,secs) {
    var disp;
    if(mins <= 9) {
        disp = " 0";
    } else {
        disp = " ";
    }
    disp += mins + " .";
    if(secs <= 9) {
        disp += "0" + secs;
    } else {
        disp += secs;
    }
    return(disp);
}

function redo() {
    secs--;
    if(secs == -1) {
        secs = 59;
        mins--;
    }
    document.cd.disp.value = dis(mins,secs); // setup additional displays here.
    if((mins == 0) && (secs == 0)) {
        window.alert(" Hey Time is up. Press OK to continue."); 
         window.location = "results_random.php" // redirects to specified page once timer ends and ok button is pressed
    } else {
        cd = setTimeout("redo()",1000);
    }
}

function init() {
  cd();
    }
     window.onload = init;
     </script>
```

The form:

```
<form name="cd">
 <label>
 <span class="labe">Remaining Time</span>:
 <input name="disp" type="text" class="clock" id="txt" value="10:00" size="10"      readonly="true" align="right" border="1" />
 <span class="labe">Minutes</span>
</form>
```

Hope you can help, thanks anyways.

Comment: Why PHP in the title? To answer your question, you should use persistent storage as localstorage or cookie but it is dependant of browser's cache. I hope i understood your question

Comment: @A.Wolff Sorry about that it's corrected now. How can I do that?

Comment: Yup nothing PHP in there, all in the client browser, and at the same time, this is your problem... If the browser page is reloaded, the state is lost, you need to find a way to keep the state!

Comment: @MathieuDumoulin yes, which is my question.

Answer (score 1):

Store the value of the timer in a cookie and pull it from that cookie, read up on cookies here: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp